# How to programatically press Tab and enter key by vb.net coding

Tags: vb.net

I am using a web browser control in which i am opening a website . On the third page of the website , there is a button . So after the loading of this 3rd page , I want to press programatically The TAB key firstly to bring the control focus on button and Then immediately pressing The ENTER key programatically on the third page of the website after its loading. I am using vb.net 2008 platform to do this. Kindly anyone plz tell me the solution ???

Comment: You should rethink your solution.  One of the biggest reasons why is that it will not work if the site's layout changes in any significant way.  There are better ways to make calls to urls than by opening a browser and emulating keystrokes.

Comment: How to emulate the keystrokes?

Comment: This was a comment, not an answer.  I don't know.  I suggest you consider a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the window handle you want to send the keys to, then send the actual keys you want.  Here are the methods necessary to do this:

```
  'API calls
  Public Declare Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd1 As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As Int32, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr
  Public Declare Function SendMessageA Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  'Function to find window by either ClassName or WindowText
  Public Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As Int32, ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal WindowName As String) As IntPtr
     Return FindWindowExA(hWndParent, hWndChildAfter, ClassName, WindowName)
  End Function

  'Function to send pressed keys to specified window by handle
  Public Shared Function SendKeyToWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal data As String) As Boolean

     Try
        Dim rc As Int32
        Dim asciiChar As Byte

        If data.Length < 1 Then          'if no data
           Return True
        End If

        'If data.Length > 1 Then
        '    data = data.ToUpper
        'End If

        'sendMessageA is used to issue messages to windows simulating keypresses
        Select Case data.ToUpper
           Case Chr(13)
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, &HD, &H1C0001)                  'send Enter Key
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_CHAR, &HD, &H1C0001)                 'send Enter Key
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, &HBE, &HC0340001)                   'send Ener Key
           Case Chr(&H9)               'tab key
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, &H9, &HF0001)                  'send tab Key
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, &H9, &HC00F0001)                 'send tab Key
           Case Else
              asciiChar = CByte(Asc(data.Substring(0, 1)))
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_CHAR, asciiChar, 0)                  'send 0 Key
        End Select

        Return True
     Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
     End Try

     Return False

  End Function
```

In your instance, you likely just need to call the sendKeyToWindow function with the handle of the webbrowser controls:

SendKeyToWindow(WebBrowser1.Handle, Chr(&H9))
  SendKeyToWindow(WebBrowser1.Handle, Chr(13))

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can u please explain the each line of the code by commenting above them

Comment: I added some comments and an example similar to what you are looking for.  I don't know if I can make it clearer than that.

Comment: can u write pllz the full coding

Comment: That is the full code.  If it's not working, then there is likely a child window handle within the web browser control.  You'd have to use Spy++ to find the window handle to send the key values to.