# Triggering TAB key to shift control by vb.net coding

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am opening a web site in a vb.net 2008 webbrowser control. I want when I open the 3rd page of the web site then after the page is loaded , control focus programmatic-ly by Triggering TAB keypresses automatically by my code . Please tell me the solution to shift the focus control ?

Comment: Why would you want to use tab to focus on different elements? Couldn't you just use javascript to focus on different elements?

Comment: no i am using vb.net to focus on a button which is on the 3rd page of the website

Comment: Don't do it this way, it is *far* more reliable to use the HtmlElement.Focus() method.  Get the element with the Document.GetElementById() method.

Comment: Document.GetElementById() method. is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically press Tab and enter key by vb.net coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150140/how-to-programatically-press-tab-and-enter-key-by-vb-net-coding)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have  understood your question right, but you could try the following,

Keep track of whether you are on the third page in your web-browser control. If you are, you can execute a JavaScript function, which changes the focus of the text-fields.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisteredStartUpScript(GetTypeOf(), "function_change_tabs", script, True)
```