# Making Enter key to work as tab key for all controls on a form vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically press Tab and enter key by vb.net coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150140/how-to-programatically-press-tab-and-enter-key-by-vb-net-coding)

As per users requirement I need to make Enter Key work as Tab Key in a VB 6.0 User input form.

For a specific control I can use 
          SendKeys "{TAB}", 
but is there any way I can make all controls on a form to take enter key as tab key.

Regards.

Raza

Comment: While this is `vb.net`, the answer will apply to `vb6` as well. [How to programatically press Tab and enter key by vb.net coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150140/how-to-programatically-press-tab-and-enter-key-by-vb-net-coding)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of controls and try something like this example:

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(Index As Integer, KeyAscii As Integer)
    'If I press Enter key...
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        With Text1(Index)
            'I add a tab.
            .Text = .Text & vbTab

            'I placed in the end of the text.
            .SelStart = Len(.Text)
        End With

        'And finally I omit the enter key pressed.
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

I've created an array of textboxes called Text1. 
I hope it helps.